# How to calculate a random series of values (B) that have a given correlation with a given series (A)

Tags: php, math, random, correlation

For an educational website, it is my purpose to let students fool around somewhat with value series and their collelation. For instance, students can enter two arrays for which the correlation is calculated:

```
$array_x = array(5,3,6,7,4,2,9,5);
$array_y = array(4,3,4,8,3,2,10,5);

echo Correlation($array_x, $array_y); // 0.93439982209434
```

The code for this works perfectly and can be found at the bottom of this post. I'm however now facing a challenge. What I want is the following:

- student inputs a $array_x (5,3,6,7,4,2,9,5)
- student inputs a correlation (0.9)
- student inputs the boundaries of $array_y (for instance, between 1 and 10 or between 50 and 80)
- the script returns a random array (for instance: 4,3,4,8,3,2,10,5) which has (about) the given correlation

So, in other words, the code would have to work like:

```
$array_x = array(5,3,6,7,4,2,9,5);
$boundaries = array(1, 10);
$correlation = 0.9;

echo ySeries($array_x, $boundaries, $correlation); // array(4,3,4,8,3,2,10,5)
```

At the Stackexchange Math forum, @ilya answered (inserted as an image, since Latex formatting of fomulas don't seem to work on stackoverflow):

[image]

P.S. The code used to calculate the correlation:

```
function Correlation($arr1, $arr2) {        
  $correlation = 0;  
  $k = SumProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2);
  $ssmd1 = SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr1);
  $ssmd2 = SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr2);
  $product = $ssmd1 * $ssmd2;
  $res = sqrt($product);
  $correlation = $k / $res;

  return $correlation;
}

function SumProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2) {
  $sum = 0;
  $num = count($arr1);
  for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + ProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2, $i);
  }
  return $sum;
}

function ProductMeanDeviation($arr1, $arr2, $item) {
  return (MeanDeviation($arr1, $item) * MeanDeviation($arr2, $item));
}

function SumSquareMeanDeviation($arr) {
  $sum = 0;
  $num = count($arr);
  for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + SquareMeanDeviation($arr, $i);
  }
  return $sum;
}

function SquareMeanDeviation($arr, $item) {
  return MeanDeviation($arr, $item) * MeanDeviation($arr, $item);
}

function SumMeanDeviation($arr) {
  $sum = 0;
  $num = count($arr);
  for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + MeanDeviation($arr, $i);
  }
  return $sum;
}

function MeanDeviation($arr, $item) {
  $average = Average($arr);
  return $arr[$item] - $average;
}    

function Average($arr) {
  $sum = Sum($arr);
  $num = count($arr);
  return $sum/$num;
}

function Sum($arr) {
  return array_sum($arr);
}
```

Comment: What is interesting about this problem is that you are looking for a way to provide students with a tool that, if I'm reading the question right, does not have a pre-defined mathematical solution (which is to say, there isn't an equation or function some Greek or French guy came up with 500+ years ago).  While the goal of wanting to pull this off is noble (and I'm going to think on it), you are basically providing a tool/function that the student couldn't actually achieve on their on (in other words, they can't plug in the numbers to confirm having already made a list of their own to confirm).

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, the purpose of this tool would be to, for instance, demonstrate that if series A is between 300 and 500, it might correlate with a series B whether the boundaries of B are 1 to 10 or much higher, say 700 to 1000. I studied economics myself, and much calculations were best understood  by having tools that let you fiddle with some properties to see the result on the other. That would be the purpose of this tool, rather than to provide proof to some Greek or Frenchs guys theorem :-)

Comment: I definitely understand the benefit of getting to play with a theorem from all angles. It definitely has helped me grasp advanced geometry (re: basic trig) better, amongst other models/systems.  I just wonder if your question isn't so much a programming issue as it is a mathematical one. I have one a few occasions realized that about dilemmas of my own, and found that asking at [math](math.stackexchange.com) helped me build a better foundation to build the code on top of.  Like I said, I think the question is valid and the goal is noble, but the answer is probably more fundamental than coding.

Comment: @Anthony please revieww the editted OP, now including some insight from the math forum. Your comments, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here's the php implementation of your algorithm that uses Dawkins' weasel to reduce the error gradually until the desired threshold.

```
<?php
function sqrMeanDeviation($array, $avg)
{
    $sqrMeanDeviation = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
    {
        $dev = $array[$i] - $avg;
        $sqrMeanDeviation += $dev * $dev;
    }

    return $sqrMeanDeviation;
}

// z values are non-0 an can value between [-abs_z_bound, abs_z_bound]
function random_z_element($abs_z_bound = 1)
{
    $a = (mt_rand() % (2*$abs_z_bound) ) - ($abs_z_bound-1);
    if($a <= 0)
        $a--;
    return $a;
}

// change z a little
function copy_z_weasel($old_array_z, $error_probability = 20 /*error possible is 1 in error_probability*/, $abs_z_bound = 1)
{
    $new_z = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($old_array_z); $i++)
        if(mt_rand() % $error_probability == 0 )
            $new_z[$i] = random_z_element($abs_z_bound);
        else
            $new_z[$i] = $old_array_z[$i];

    return $new_z;
}

function correlation_error($array_y, $array_x, $avg_x, $sqrMeanDeviation_x, $correlation)
{
    // checking correlation
    $avg_y = array_sum($array_y)/count($array_y);

    $sqrMeanDeviation_y = 0;
    $covariance_xy = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<count($array_x); $i++)
    {
        $dev_y = $array_y[$i] - $avg_y;
        $sqrMeanDeviation_y += $dev_y * $dev_y;

        $dev_x = $array_x[$i] - $avg_x;
        $covariance_xy += $dev_y * $dev_x;
    }
    $correlation_xy = $covariance_xy/sqrt($sqrMeanDeviation_x*$sqrMeanDeviation_y);
    return abs($correlation_xy - $correlation);
}

function ySeries($array_x, $low_bound, $high_bound, $correlation, $threshold)
{
    $array_y = array();

    $avg_x = array_sum($array_x)/count($array_x);
    $sqrMeanDeviation_x = sqrMeanDeviation($array_x, $avg_x);

    // pre-compute beta
    $beta_x_sQMz = $sqrMeanDeviation_x * sqrt( 1 / ($correlation*$correlation) - 1 );

    $best_array_z = array();
    $n = 0;
    $error = $threshold + 1;

    while($error > $threshold)
    {
        ++$n;

        // generate z 
        $array_z = array();
        if(count($best_array_z) == 0)
            for($i=0; $i<count($array_x); $i++)
                $array_z[$i] = random_z_element();
        else
            $array_z = copy_z_weasel($best_array_z);

        $sqm_z = sqrMeanDeviation($array_z, array_sum($array_z)/count($array_z) );
        // this being 0 implies that for every beta correlation(x,y) = 1 so just give it any random beta
        if($sqm_z)
            $beta = $beta_x_sQMz / $sqm_z;
        else
            $beta = 10;
        // and now we have y
        for($i=0; $i<count($array_x); $i++)
            $array_y[$i] = $array_x[$i] + ($array_z[$i] * $beta);

        // now, change bounds (we could do this afterwards but we want precision and y to be integers)
        // rounding
        $min_y = $array_y[0];
        $max_y = $array_y[0];
        for( $i=1; $i<count($array_x); $i++ )
        {
            if($array_y[$i] < $min_y)
                $min_y = $array_y[$i];
            if($array_y[$i] > $max_y)
                $max_y = $array_y[$i];
        }

        $range = ($high_bound - $low_bound) / ($max_y - $min_y);
        $shift = $low_bound - $min_y;
        for( $i=0; $i<count($array_x); $i++ )
            $array_y[$i] = round($array_y[$i] * $range + $shift);

        // get the error
        $new_error = correlation_error($array_y, $array_x, $avg_x, $sqrMeanDeviation_x, $correlation);

        if($new_error < $error)
        {
            $best_array_z = $array_z;
            $error = $new_error;
        }

    }
    echo "Correlation ", $correlation, " approched within " , $new_error, " in ", $n ," iterations.\n";

    return $array_y;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I don't understand ... you speak off an average difference of 0.001 ... I get many differences between -0.1 and 0.8 on a requested correlation of 0.7. How is such a difference with your results possible? I'm using your code with `$array_x = array(5,3,6,7,4,2,9,5); $low_bound = 100; $high_bound = 130; $correlation = 0.7;` Any ideas? Is it possible to enhance the algorithms accuracy or let the function repeat itself if the correlation has a difference above a certain threshold, say 0.05?

Comment: I am surprised by the variance of the error (the value abs($correlation_xy - $correlation)) but I did only a quick testing, with a big number of random input values (array_x and correlation) and the average error was low. That's why I suggested you add a loop to control the maximum error. But I'll edit to include that since I like Alex's idea.

Answer (score 3):

a simple approach, although very inefficient, would be to start with a random number in the given interval and try to add more numbers, as long as they don't violate the correlation too much:

```
function ySeries(array_x, boundaries, correlation) {
  array_y = [random(boundaries)]
  while (len(array_y) < len(array_x)) {
    do {    
      y = random(boundaries)
    } while (Correlation(array_x, array_y + [y]) > correlation + epsilon)

    array_y.push(y)
  }
}
```

might work well, as long as the numbers are small

Comment: as a variant: initialize array_y = array_x and disturb the values randomly in the same fashion as above, controlling the correlation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? From where do you get the epsilon?

Comment: it's a deviation from the given correlation that you are willing to tolerate, a constant chosen by yourself. should be more something like  ... while |Correlation(..) - correlation| > epsilon

Comment: See the editted opening post, which includes some insight from the math forum. Your comments, please?